# Java XML parsing using DOM to get nodevalue

Tags: java, xml, dom

```
    try {
        String data = "<a><b c='d' e='f'>0.15</b></a>";
        DocumentBuilderFactory documentBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory
                .newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder documentBuilder = documentBuilderFactory
                .newDocumentBuilder();
        InputSource is = new InputSource();
        is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(data));
        Document document = documentBuilder.parse(is);

        NodeList nl = document.getElementsByTagName("b");
        Node n = (Node) nl.item(0);
        System.out.println(n.getNodeValue());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Exception " + e);

    }
```

I am expecting it to print 0.15, but it prints null. Any Ideas?

Edit: This did the trick

```
        if (n.hasChildNodes())
            System.out.println(n.getFirstChild().getNodeValue());
        else 
            System.out.println(n.getNodeValue());
```

Answer (score 11):

That's because [an element in fact has no `nodeValue`](http://faq.javaranch.com/java/GetNodeValue). Instead it has a text node as a child, which has the `nodeValue` you want.

In short, you'll want to `getNodeValue()` on the first child of the element node.

Sometimes the element contains multiple text nodes, as they do have a maximum size, in which case you'll need something á la this, from the page linked earlier:

```
public static String getNodeValue(Node node) {
    StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer();
    NodeList children = node.getChildNodes();
    for (int i = 0; i < children.getLength(); i++) {
        Node textChild = children.item(i);
        if (textChild.getNodeType() != Node.TEXT_NODE) {
            System.err.println("Mixed content! Skipping child element " + textChild.getNodeName());
            continue;
        }
        buf.append(textChild.getNodeValue());
    }
    return buf.toString();
}
```

Comment: Good explanation, and thanks much for the excellent function.  Works like a champ.

Answer (score 7):

Try extracting it from the Element rather than from the Node:

```
try {
    String data = "<a><b c='d' e='f'>0.15</b></a>";
    DocumentBuilderFactory documentBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory
            .newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder documentBuilder = documentBuilderFactory
            .newDocumentBuilder();
    InputSource is = new InputSource();
    is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(data));
    Document document = documentBuilder.parse(is);

    NodeList nl = document.getElementsByTagName("b");
    Element el = (Element) nl.item(0);
    Text elText = (Text) el.getFirstChild();
    String theValue = elText.getNodeValue();
    System.out.println(theValue);
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("Exception " + e);
}
```

Comment: @mkal - I just edited to output the nodevalue instead of the Text instance!

Answer (score 3):

```
System.out.println(n.getFirstChild().getNodeValue());
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 private String getTextValue(Element element, String string) {
    String textVal = null;
    NodeList nl = element.getElementsByTagName(string);
    if(nl != null && nl.getLength() > 0) {
        Element el = (Element)nl.item(0);
        textVal = el.getFirstChild().getNodeValue();
    }

    return textVal;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

If the node has no further nested descendants, than `n.getTextContent()` works quite well.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [jOOX](http://code.google.com/p/joox/) as a wrapper for standard DOM, to simplify your code.

```
String data = "<a><b c='d' e='f'>0.15</b></a>";
String value = $(data).find("b").text();
```

You could also have jOOX convert that value to double, for instance:

```
Double value = $(data).find("b").text(Double.class);
```